# ESXi 5.5.0 - Random Host Reboots

Tags: vmware-esxi

Hello i have a ProLiant ML350 G5 server (Xeon E5420, 16Gb RAM) that runs ESXi 5.5.0 build 1623387 and hosts 3 VMs.

The last few days server started rebooting with no reason.

I don't know what to look for in the logs. Can anyone help me out or point me to some direction?

Log files: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=84450166064963890641

Health Status on server is OK unless it's a hardware part that it can't picked up by the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked in iLO land iLO logs for any hardware issues

Comment: Stating the obvious, 5.5 isn't supported on ML350 G5 - http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/vmware.aspx

Comment: @BlueCompute The thing is that the server had an uptime of 300 days with no problems. So i can't see why it's not supported on that chart. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the server updated itself to newer version?

Comment: The server or ESXi?  No.

Comment: Before all you need to check RAM memory via memtest 86. If memory is OK then change motherboard.